# Get Spinners' text send to mail

Tags: java, android, email, spinner

I just started learning coding in android studio.....
and i have this little problem that i want to resolve!
I want to get the text from spinners and editText and put it to mail's body!
I have learned how to get editText's text and get it in mail. I just want to add spinners' text also but i really dont know how.
Here is my xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.virtusplus.sofronis_systems.Contactform">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/static_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#dce1e3"
        android:background="#dce1e3"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:popupBackground="#dce1e3" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#dce1e3"
        android:popupBackground="#dce1e3"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Επιλέξτε προϊόν:"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Ποσότητα:"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/static_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Ονοματεπώνυμο:"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dynamic_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Σχόλια:"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:id="@+id/sendEmail"
        android:background="#0e89cc"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my javaclass:

```js
package com.virtusplus.sofronis_systems;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Contactform extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText subject;
    private EditText body;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contactform);

        Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.brew_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        staticAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

        Spinner dynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);

        String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

        dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        dynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
        body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

        Button sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendEmail();
                // after sending the email, clear the fields
                subject.setText("");
                body.setText("");
            }
        });
        String message = staticSpinner.getSelectedItem() +"and"+ dynamicSpinner.getSelectedItem() + body.getText().toString();

    }

    protected void sendEmail() {


        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        // prompts email clients only
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        String[] to={"example@mail.com"};
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.getText().toString());

        try {
            // the user can choose the email client
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an email client"));

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Contactform.this, "No email client installed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thnx in advance!

Comment: You get the currently selected Spinner value by saying spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be you were missing a call toString()

```
String message = staticSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() +"and"+ dynamicSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + body.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected text like this:

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And add to the mail's body:

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.getText().toString() + text);
```

Comment: but still where should i put it so it can be in the mail's body?